# git on bash - how to TAB to based on list of modified files

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete

My Git repository has deeply nested folders containing my source files.

When I modify a few files, the first 5 folders are often common and TABing to refer to a file is annoying.

When I type `git diff <TAB>`, is it possible to have **TAB** auto-complete based on the modified files from `git status`?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but you can always use glob patterns, like `git diff */yourfile`.

Comment: One may customize autocomplete functionality, known as Programmable Completion https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html

Ideally, there is someone who already did this for git software. You can also try it yourself if you can afford the time and effort.